# What is the difference between reference and deference?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between reference and deference? Is it true that it could be that reference is giving respect or showing respect, which means that reference could mean deference? Deference's meaning is what I don't get.

Comment: They have very different meanings. Have you looked them up in a dictionary?

Comment: I think you might mean reverence, not reference?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously looking up in the dictionary will be more precise - however I would offer that they are antonyms conceptually. References are employed to support a position, where deference is declaring someone is held as so definitive an authority on a position, no reference of support is required.